# Best way to update old answers when links have changed?

Tags: discussion, editing

**tl;dr : I commented on an old answer to show corrected links.  Is there a better way?**

This has recently come up for me because of the accepted answer for this question:
[Is there a way to autodetect when a display is disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7292/is-there-a-way-to-autodetect-when-a-display-is-disconnected/10089#10089)

There were at least two outdated pieces of information which required updating, and for now, anyway, I've just left comments indicating this.

I would probably just edit the current answer if there was a one-for-one link replacement available, but I don't think that is the case here. Furthermore, I can't test the updated information because I don't have the set-up described in the question.

Should I nevertheless have put the updates inline in the answer, somehow, or are comments a reasonable way to do this?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just use your editing powers -- you have over 2k rep so click edit and edit generously to make improvements. What good are superpowers for great justice if you don't use them?! :)

( and, even anonymous users can submit suggested edits: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/ )

Answer (score 4):

The Review system should have an option for searching for posts with deadlinks. I don't know if this will overtax the StackOverflow servers, though.

Comment: I love magic potions.

Comment: This is [in the making](http://askubuntu.com/review/broken-links) (not fully functional yet though).

Comment: @belacqua I meant to say "option", not "potion"(sorry for ignorance)

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS  I know, yet I couldn't resist.  It was clearly a typo, but it was a nice one.

Comment: @EliahKagan Hmm. What about automatically using the Internet archive(Wayback machine) to automatically fix bad links as a temporary measure until a new one can be suggested?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I recommend posting a new question, requesting this feature. Then it can be discussed by itself.