# Using Wayback Machine of internet archive

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks, review

I have read on a [different meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1182/best-way-to-update-old-answers-when-links-have-changed/3420#comment5239_3420) that there is a [system](https://askubuntu.com/review/broken-links) being implemented to fix bad links systematically. Could it be set up to automatically use the [Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org) to automatically redirect until a reviewer finds a more up-to-date link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the link is broken the the answer probably needs to be updated, why not just fix the answer to be correct?

Comment: I agree with this one.

Comment: Often, the link was hard-to-find in the first place or is official, but discontinued.